# My incorrect edit got approved before I was able to fix it - What could / should I do?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I suggested an edit to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678062/setting-the-width-and-height-of-a-jcomponent-as-instance-variables) a while ago. Now, the edit was not purposefully / maliciously made incorrect. [Actually, the post has been edited 1 time since I began](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24678062/revisions) and the author added tags, which were not carried over to my edit:

[image: lol]

[This was my suggested edit, note that the tags were removed accidentally:](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5267578)

[image: lol]

I thought of adding a note in a comment informing the OP to re-add the tags from revision 2 if he would like, or even posting a new edit. However, I was uncertain for:

1. Whether re-tagging the question was unnecessary in this case?
2. Shouldn't the edit have had been rejected as it's incorrect and removes relevant tags?
3. What should / can I do as a follow-up? (I'm really concerned, especially if my edit shows up in a future audit and get reviewers punished for rejecting my edit properly.)

Thanks in advance! All comments / insights are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You shouldn't make another edit just to add those two tags, no.  That edit would really be too minor on its own.  Let someone with full editing privileges make the change.
2. Ideally it would just have been improved to add the tags back in, rather than rejecting the edit, especially if the reviewers noticed that it was the result of conflicting edits.
3. Meh, it's not a *huge* deal here.  The [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag gives it the majority of its attention, which is generally sufficient either on its own (as was the case here) or to at least find someone else to add in some more specific tags.  If the mis-tagging were such that it would likely fail to get enough [relevant] attention to be at least fixed, then it may be concerning enough to suggest an edit over it.  This would be the case if say it was missing a primary language tag.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that any edit that only affects tags can **never** be "Too Minor".  When I review such changes I only consider if the tag edits are valid (the tags apply, they are good choices, nothing is obviously left out).  Tags have a large effect on the visibility and attention of a post, so I believe any change to them is important.

If you feel that **important** tags are missing, please do make an edit.